# Setting Form(subForm) recordsource equal to ComboBox

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

Having problem setting `recordsource` for form (and subform) to combobox(0) 'value'.

I have a statement that determine if the openArgs is from another form.  If not, I want to able to set use the combobox in main to change the current record.  Obviously, if don't do anything it with default to '0' as openArgs.

```vb
Private Sub cmbMemNam_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strMemNam As String
    strMemNam = "SELECT tblMembers.*, tblMembers.[mbr_ID] FROM tblMembers WHERE ((tblMembers.[mbr_ID]) = '" & (Nz(Me.cmbMemNam.Column(0)) & "')"
    Me.RecordSource = strMemNam
End Sub
```

I'm getting a compile error. I'm trying to locate a site that list the proper order of syntax for objects and SQL statements.  I guess it just take practice.

Before the guru's jump on me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses surrounding your `Nz` expression:

```vb
( Nz ( Me.cmbMemNam.Column(0) )
```

Should be:

```vb
Nz(Me.cmbMemNam.Column(0))
```

Comment: That cleared up the error, and I don't know if this is appropriate or whether I'm suppose to start a new question but I'm getting a runtime error after I set variable string 'strMemNam: here example

Comment: That cleared up the error, and I don't know if this is appropriate or whether I'm suppose to start a new question but I'm getting a runtime error after I set variable string 'strMemNam: here example on next line.
   Me.Filter = strMemNam

Comment: Your filter can't be a select statement. It should be along the lines of `mbr_ID=12`